# Windows Server- Is there a way to get CPU Usage over a period by a specific program?

Tags: windows, powershell, resources

I need to get the Processes consuming CPU the most and **over what time**. Is this possible using any counter or script?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This at least gets you the info on who's using up the CPU. As to when, well that's another question entiresly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Isn't there a way to identify when they occur?

Comment: Not that I am currently aware of. But I'm thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should configure a data collector set in Performance Monitor (PerfMon).  You can collect the counter "\Process(*)% Processor Time".  You can roll over the collector files for analysis later and hence see process performance over time.

When you look at the files later the graphs should make it easier to find the process that's consuming more CPU.  I can't bang out a full tutorial at the moment, but a simple google search should turn up plenty of instructional info.

I will say the biggest challenge is configuring the schedule just right to make sure you capturing all the data you need.  If that starts getting confusing there's a folder buried in Task Manager called PLA.  That's for Performance Logs & Alerts.  You should find a job there that correlates to your collector.  It may be easier to work on the schedule there...

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, I tried using the above mentioned counters but it didn't return the processes using the CPU. Any workaround?

Comment: Assuming you did the collections correctly they should be in the file but you may need to add them.  In PerfMon right click the graph area and choose add counters. You should see all the counters that were added to the collector. Select and add them.  Let me know.